# jQuery - Links Stop Working After Page Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make my website responsive and have added some jQuery to remove and insert HTML. I am trying to display a popup box when an anchor tag around an image is clicked.

The window appears the first time the page is loaded, but when it has been resized the link no longer works and doesn't display the popup.

```
    // Call hidePopup function upon clicking element with class ".close"
    $(function() {
        $('.close').click(hidePopup);
    });
    function hidePopup() {
        if (this.id == 'hideP1') {
            $('#popup1').addClass('hidePopups');
        } else if (this.id == 'hideP2') {
            $('#popup2').addClass('hidePopups');
        } else if (this.id == 'hideP3') {
            $('#popup3').addClass('hidePopups');
        }
    }

    // Call showPopup function upon clicking element with class ".imgClick"
    $(function() {
        $('.imgClick').click(showPopup);
    });
    function showPopup() {
        if (this.id == 'imgEms') {
            $('#popup1').removeClass('hidePopups');
        } else if (this.id == 'imgPas') {
            $('#popup2').removeClass('hidePopups');
        } else if (this.id == 'imgTs') {
            $('#popup3').removeClass('hidePopups');
        }
    } 
    var LinkedHtml = [
        '<a href="#popup1" class="imgClick" id="imgEms" onclick="showPopup()"><img src="assets/img/festival-big.jpg" title="Event Medical Services"></a>',
        '<a href="#popup2" class="imgClick" id="imgPas" onclick="showPopup()"><img src="assets/img/ambulance2.png" title="Private Ambulance Services"></a>',
        '<a href="#popup3" class="imgClick" id="imgTs" onclick="showPopup()"><img src="assets/img/training_1.jpeg" title="Training Solutions"></a>'
    ];
    var nonLinkedHtml = [
        '<img src="assets/img/festival-big.jpg" title="Event Medical Services" id="emsImg">',
        '<img src="assets/img/ambulance2.png" title="Private Ambulance Services" id="pasImg">',
        '<img src="assets/img/training_1.jpeg" title="Training Solutions" id="tsImg">'
    ];

    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowSize = $(window).width();
        var anchorIds = ['#imgEms','#imgPas','#imgTs'];
        var imageIds = ['#emsImg','#pasImg','#tsImg'];

        if (windowSize < 740) {
            for (var i = 0; i < imageIds.length; i++) {
                $(imageIds[i]).replaceWith(LinkedHtml[i]);
            } 
        } else if (windowSize > 740) {
            $(".overlay").addClass("hidePopups");
            for (var i = 0; i < anchorIds.length; i++) {
                $(anchorIds[i]).replaceWith(nonLinkedHtml[i]);
            } 
        }
    });
```

I do not have much experience with JavaScript nor jQuery and I have been struggling with this issue all day.

Thank you!

Comment: Open your console (F12) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @Taplar The only error that appears is `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.` but that hasn't affected it before.

Comment: Alright, for shiggles change `onclick="showPopup()"` to `onclick="showPopup(this)"`  and change your method to accept in an element.  When you replace the elements, the bindings on the new elements don't exist.  So all you have is your onclick inline binding.

Comment: Optionally if you have a common parent for all the elements that you are replacing, you could change your binding to be a delegate binding and it wouldn't matter if you replaced them later.

Comment: @Taplar no success unfortunately. I'll try your updated method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try to use a delegate instead?

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', '.imgClick', showPopup);
});
```

If this works, then you should try to find a parent element that always exists for the imgClick elements, that is never replaced, and use that as a selector instead of `document.body`.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you for your help and making it easy to understand!